# Execute an program (.exe) as a thread - Window C++

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I using the thread class to create threads,
but I'm having some trouble of running another program as a thread.
I want a way to create and run an .exe thread by its path.
something like exec syscalls in linux, only for threads and in window.
(replaces the current thread image with a new thread image)

Also, how can I communicate with this thread? (something like using pipes and dup in linux)

Thanks in advance,
Yuval.

Comment: You can't do that. you can only execute an executable as its own process, not as a thread within another process

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the current thread image". Threads don't have images. Processes do.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do that by writing/using a home made PE loader and jumping to the start address once you filled the IAT, fixed the rellocations and found a solution to TLS...

Something like this : https://github.com/abhisek/Pe-Loader-Sample should be able to help you.